# How to do on scroll pagination in flutter from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flutter, pagination

How to implement infinite pagination with MongoDB in flutter. to get 10 items on scroll in order to not get all the documents at once. how to make an app with MongoDB to retrieve the data on scroll. Like if I scroll to the end the flutter should load 10 more documents from MongoDB.